# AWS ALB ingress resource path definition

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, amazon-eks, aws-application-load-balancer

I am trying to configure an aws alb ingress for an existing cluster which already has nginx ingress configured. This is the resource file I'm using in nginx ingress which works fine.

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: "stage-ingress-1"
  namespace: "teststage"
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: alb
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: HTTP
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/listen-ports: '[{"HTTP": 80}, {"HTTPS": 443}]'
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/certificate-arn:  <cert_arn>
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/actions.ssl-redirect: '{"Type": "redirect", "RedirectConfig": { "Protocol": "HTTPS", "Port": "443", "StatusCode": "HTTP_301"}}'
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/target-type: ip
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/scheme: internet-facing
  labels:
    app: test-ingress
spec:
  rules:
    - http:
        paths:
          - path: /(.*)
            backend:
              serviceName: ssl-redirect
              servicePort: use-annotation
          - path: /(.*)
            backend:
              serviceName: "test-service"
              servicePort: 80
      host: test.abc.com
```

However, I get an error saying

`"msg"="Reconciler error" "error"="failed to reconcile listeners due to failed to reconcile rules due to failed modifying rule 2 on aws alb due to ValidationError: Condition value '/(.*)' contains a character that is not valid`

I understand it is something to do with the path specified, but I do not get on how this has to be configured. This is the path which contains all my data.

Answer (score 2):

It is not regex.  Its much more simple matching than that
you want.

```
spec:
  rules:
    - http:
        paths:
          - path: /*
            backend:
              serviceName: ssl-redirect
              servicePort: use-annotation
          - path: /*
            backend:
              serviceName: "test-service"
              servicePort: 80
      host: test.abc.com
```